# CSS ease in and out on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I have a simple div that is round with a `border-radius` of 50%. On `hover` the border radius changes to zero. I have used the following css code which works perfectly.

```css
.design-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.design-box:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="design-box"></div>
```

What I would like to happen is that when the div is no longer hovered I would like the transition to `ease out` and slowly transform back to the original `border-radius` of 50%. I cant quite get it to work, am I missing a simple step here?

Thank you

Comment: add the transitions to the .design-box class, not the hover

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put `transition` only on the normal state:

```
.design-box {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.design-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-box:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="design-box"></div>
```